# Why "SE" in "no se me ocurre ..."?

Tags: gramática

Why does this (native) Spanish speaker used "se" in this sentence: "no **se** me ocurre ninguna frase en español para expresar lo mismo"?

Gracias!

Comment: Occurirse is the verb, so "se ocurre" = it occurs. "se me occure" = it occurs to me

Comment: @aris The correct spelling is *ocurrir*.

Answer (score 1):

The sixth definition given in the [DLE](https://dle.rae.es/ocurrir?m=form) for *ocurrir* is

> 6. prnl. Dicho de una idea: Venirse a la mente de repente y sin esperarla. Era u. t. c. intr.

So as a pronominal verb it means: of an idea, to come suddenly and unexpectedly to mind. If you are an English speaker you may have been taught these as reflexive but Spanish distinguishes various uses of *se* with a verb.

You might like to look also at questions and answers on this site tagged [verbo-pronominal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbo-pronominal)

In answer to a further question posed by the OP in a comment perhaps I should have stated that in this use *ocurrir* is only used in the third person. In this case *ocurre* is third person. As a piece of geneal advice I suggest that trying to translate all the component parts of pronominal verbs is a recipe for confusion. You just have to accept that they work the way they do, not spend time wondering from the sign on a house *Se vende* how it is that Spanish houses are clever enough to sell themselves.

Comment: but isn't the "me" in "se me ocurre" the "se" in ocurrirse? what about the "se"?

Comment: @Celso mdewey is right. "Le" is the indirect object, which is obligatory for this pronominal verb (**ocurrírsele** a alguien algo): se me ocurre, se te ocurre, se le ocurre, etc.

Comment: @Celso From your profile I see you've studied German, so maybe you've come across the verb *einfallen*. It's not pronominal like *ocurrirse* but it's used in the third person and the dative object points to the person who gets the idea. *Mir fällt nichts Besseres ein* is almost exactly parallel to *No se me ocurre nada mejor*.